# Convert c++ dll call to delphi with message handler

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, delphi-xe3

I need to use a DLL in my delphi XE3 application, I've received a demo application written in c++ that shows how to call the DLL.
I've succeed in calling the DLL and the Initialize method of the dll, but I don't get any messages back from the DLL.
This is the c++ source:
Creating the message handler:

```
#define WM_POSSTATE  WM_APP+1
#define ON_WM_POSSTATE() \
{ WM_POSSTATE, 0, 0, 0, AfxSig_vwl, \
    (AFX_PMSG)(AFX_PMSGW)(void (AFX_MSG_CALL CWnd::*)(UINT, LPARAM))&OnPOS },
```

Definition of the Initialize method:

```
typedef int (INITIALIZE)( char * cPort , UINT Msg, HWND *hWnd_p );
INITIALIZE *Initialize;

HMODULE         hPosDll;
```

Loading the DLL:

```
if( (hPosDll = LoadLibrary( "posdll.dll" ) ) == NULL )
{
    MessageBox( "Error: can not open posdll.dll",NULL,MB_OK);
    exit(1);
}

if( (::Initialize = (INITIALIZE*)GetProcAddress( hPosDll, "Initialize" )) == NULL )
{
    MessageBox( "Error: can not find function",NULL,MB_OK);
    FreeLibrary( hPosDll );
    exit(1);
}
```

Calling the Initialize method:

```
res=::Initialize('com3', WM_POSSTATE , &m_hWnd);

if( res )
{
    MessageBox( "Error opening comms",NULL,MB_OK);
    FreeLibrary( hPosDll );
    exit(1);
}
```

After the Initialize call, messages from the DLL to the application are processed by the OnPos methos:

```
void CPosDemoDlg::OnPOS(UINT Result, LPARAM Param )
{
    DoStuff;
}
```

In Delphi I've come so far:

```
unit UFrmMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, MCPOSDLL;

const
  WM_POSSTATE = WM_APP + 1;
  MCDLL = 'posdll.dll';

type
  TInitialize = function(cport: PAnsiChar; Msg: Integer; Handle: HWND):Integer; stdcall;

  TFrmMain = class(TForm)
    EdCOMPort: TEdit;
    BtnConnect: TButton;
    LblCOMPort: TLabel;
    procedure ON_WM_POSSTATE(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_POSSTATE;
    procedure BtnConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    DLLHandle: THandle;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FrmMain: TFrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
 procedure TFrmMain.BtnConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
 var
   MCInitialize: TInitialize;
   Res: Integer;
 begin
   DLLHandle := LoadLibrary(PChar(MCDLL));

   if DLLHandle <> 0 then
     begin
       @MCInitialize := getProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'Initialize');

       if @MCInitialize <> NIL then
         begin
           Res := MCInitialize(PAnsiChar('com3'), WM_POSSTATE, Self.Handle);

           if Res <> 0 then
             begin
               MessageDlg('Error opening comms', mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
             end;
         end;
     end
   else
     begin
       MessageDlg('posdll.dll could not be located.', mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
     end;
 end;

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
 procedure TFrmMain.ON_WM_POSSTATE(var Msg: TMessage);
 begin
   showmessage('Message received');
 end;

end.
```

With this solution I'm able to activate the device connected to com3 but the messagehandler is never triggered.
I think the `&m_hWnd` that is send with the Initialize method in c++ is not the same as the `Self.Handle` I'm sending in Delphi.
Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance, it looks like your declaration

```
TInitialize = function(cport: PAnsiChar; Msg: Integer; Handle: HWND):Integer;
```

does not match

```
typedef int (INITIALIZE)( char * cPort , UINT Msg, HWND *hWnd_p );
```

Note that the C declaration expects a *pointer* to the variable holding the handle.

Try

```
TInitialize = function(cport: PAnsiChar; Msg: Integer; var Handle: HWND):Integer;
```

and see how far you get.

Comment: @Hanno You ought to fix the code so that it compiles. You cannot write `Handle: ^HWND` in a parameter list.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ function is declared as:

```
typedef int (INITIALIZE)( char * cPort , UINT Msg, HWND *hWnd_p );
```

Your Delphi equivalent is declared as:

```
TInitialize = function(cport: PAnsiChar; Msg: Integer; 
  Handle: HWND): Integer; stdcall;
```

I can see the following differences in your Delphi declaration:

1. The `Msg` parameter is unsigned, but the Delphi translation is signed.
2. The `hWnd_p` parameter is a pointer to `HWND`. In the Delphi you pass the window handle by value.
3. The calling convention of the C++ code is `cdecl`, but you declared the Delphi code as `stdcall`.

So in Delphi the declaration should be:

```
TInitialize = function(cport: PAnsiChar; Msg: Cardinal; 
  Handle: PHWND): Integer; cdecl;
```

where `PHWND` is a type declared to be `^HWND`. I suspect that such a type is declared in the `Windows` unit but if not then you can readily declare it.

Or perhaps a simpler translation would be:

```
TInitialize = function(cport: PAnsiChar; Msg: Cardinal; 
  var Handle: HWND): Integer; cdecl;
```

Of course, it's plausible that you omitted the calling convention when you transcribed the C++ code. Perhaps the function really is `stdcall` even though the declaration you placed in the question did not say so.

Beyond that your code is using the window handle of the form. This can be risky. In some situations the VCL re-creates windows. This would lead to the handle that you passed to the DLL being destroyed. The DLL would carry on sending messages to that window but your form would stop receiving them because its window had changed.

The way around this is to use a window handle that the VCL will not re-create. Get one of those by calling `AllocateHwnd`.

Be careful when you call `Initialize`. You pass `PAnsiChar('com3')` as the port name. You need to be sure that the literal `'com3'` really is ANSI encoded. Ideally you should pass `'com3'` directly to `Initialize`. If that doesn't compile (I'm not sure off the top of my head if it will or not) then pass `PAnsiChar(AnsiString('com3'))`.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Hanno and David, I changed my code and it's working now.

Changes I've made:

```
type
  PHWND = ^HWnd;    
  TInitialize = function(cport: PAnsiChar; Msg: Cardinal; Handle: PHWND):Integer; stdcall;
```

and

```
var 
  TmpHandle
begin
  ...
  TmpHandle := Self.Handle;
  Res := MCInitialize(PAnsiChar(AnsiString('com3')), WM_POSSTATE, @TmpHandle);
```

Following the advice of David Hefferman I'l create a separate component in the final application, this way I'll use `AllocateHwnd` to create a fixed handle.
      ...

Comment: We don't really need this answer. You are just repeating what I said in my answer. Which seems odd given that you accepted the other answer.